# How do I calculate a cumulative average over time across isolated cells in the same row?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'd like to know how to write a formula that will calculate a running average of totals in a given row when the cells containing those totals are isolated. An example of the spreadsheet I am working on and what I would like it to do can be found [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bExeHGweyoqniL9QnEI5-QKifKv1z_NLbLm40KBhsRw/edit?usp=sharing)

The challenge I have run into specifically is getting the "Monthly Average" formula to consider all "Monthly Total" cells prior to the current "Monthly Average" cell.

I can write a formula that will check each cell in Row 32 for a "Monthly Total" value and SUM all of the values adjacent to these cells and then AVERAGE the the resulting SUM against the number of values considered but problematically that makes every single "Monthly Average" cell produce the exact same result as they will all consider all "Monthly Total" values both prior to and after the "Monthly Average" cell. This limits me to only having access to the current monthly average and prevents me from having any historical insight on the running average over time. I would like each "Monthly Average" cell to only represent data prior to its place within the sheet so I can look back and see what the monthly average was at any given month prior to the current month.

I could also write a query to select a range(32:32 in this case) and produce an average by checking the row for a given value using the where and like arguments `=index(query({32:32},"select AVG(Col11), AVG(Col27) where Col10 like '%Monthly Total%'"), 2)` but that presents the same issue as above, and introduces a new one. It prints multiple results to multiple adjacent cells. I don't know how to limit it to just the data preciding it or how to make it write the average of the two results into a single value in a single cell.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this formula direct into cells (`K33, AA33...`) that needs to be filled with ***`Monthly Average`*** number while ***taking into the account only the current & all preceeding `Monthly Totals`*** for calculation

```
=average(indirect("A32:"&address(32,column(),4)))
```

[image]